# De una lista seleccionar solo los registros con un valor de campo diferente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito seleccionar de una lista solo los registros que tengan un valor de campo diferente.

Es decir, en la siguiente lista selecciono todos los valores diferentes del campo 'Descripcion':

```
ID Producto Euros Descripcion
1     AA      5     PERAS
2     BB      7     PERAS
3     CC      2     NARANJAS
4     DD      8     NARANJAS
5     EE      9     MANZANAS
6     FF      7     PIÑAS
7     GG      3     PIÑAS
8     HH      5     PIÑAS
```

La consulta deberia devolverme por ejemplo:

```
ID Producto Euros Descripcion
1     AA      5     PERAS
3     CC      2     NARANJAS
5     EE      9     MANZANAS
6     FF      7     PIÑAS
```

Nota: El nombre de los valores que puede contener 'Descripcion' son desconocidos.

Una aproximación podria ser:

```
 select distinct Descripcion from tabla
```

Pero quiero que me muestre tambien campo ID, campo Producto y campo Euros. Tambien me interesaria que del resultado mostrado me filtrara por todos los campos Producto donde sea = 'AA'

Comment: pues bien, la salida, no es nada logica... lo que se muestra en los otros 3 campos, que es? en base a que? son el menor algebraico? si es asi, es un simple group by con min...

Comment: Los otros tres campos deben estar y me sirve cualquier valor que contenga para ese campo Descripcion. Pongamos que me muestra el primer registro encontrado para esa Descripcion.

Comment: Si te sirve cualquier valor, claramente no te sirven....

Comment: Qué motor de BD?

Comment: El motor es SQL SERVER

Comment: La pregunta se edita.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es relativamente simple de lograr con `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Descripcion ORDER BY ID) RN
    FROM dbo.Tabla
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

Comment: no es un simple group by? o un distinct? no tiene sentido ningun valor de los otros.. y row_number si fuera sql server no? ;)

Comment: `GROUP BY` o `DISTINCT` no entregarían el resultado que quiere el op, ya que finalmente quiere una fila específica por cada valor diferente de `Descripcion`. `ROW_NUMBER` es parte del estándar ANSI sql, por lo que varios motores de bases de datos lo implementan de una u otra forma; sin embargo, esta sintaxis específica es para SQL Server, tienes razón